# How to use the verb 'Remember'

Tags: verbs

Here's a context.

A month ago, I met a friend of mine and we talked about him going to America next year. And I met him again yesterday, but I don't remember what exactly we talked about. So, at that time, I said like this:

> 1. I vaguely remember ***you saying that*** you ***are*** thinking of going to America next year, right?
> 2. I vaguely remember ***you saying that*** you ***were*** thinking of going to America next year, right?
> 3. I vaguely remember ***you said that*** you were thinking of going to America next year, right?
> 4. I vaguely remember ***you said something about*** you going to America next year, right?
> 5. I vaguely remember ***you saying something about*** you going to America next year, right?

.#1 - has to be were

And the others have difference in vagueness, but all are possible and common to use right?

PS. remember and recall is interchangeable without changing any nuance?

Comment: @user3169 Why does it eliminate 2? 2 would be my preference, personally... Or 5, for that matter... other than the extra "you" mentioned below, 5 sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @jihoon, The second "you" in options 4 and 5 (before "going to America") really isn't necessary. "I vaguely remember you saying something about going to America next year, right?" It's not *wrong*, as it does emphasize that your friend is the one going to the US, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

They would all be understood perfectly by a native English speaker. The differences are subtle.

> 1. I vaguely remember you saying that you are thinking of going to America next year, right?

This implies that you believe that he is still intending to go to America.

> 2. I vaguely remember you saying that you were thinking of going to America next year, right?

This would imply that *at the time* he was thinking of going, but that you are not sure if he still plans to actually go. This would normally be a subjective opinion - perhaps they were unsure, or implied that they expected something to arise that would prevent the visit.

> 3. I vaguely remember you said that you were thinking of going to America next year, right?

More neutral - you are repeating back to the friend what you remember of the conversation, nothing more.

> 4 & 5. I vaguely remember you said/saying something about you going to America next year, right?

Both are largely interchangeable, but would be more of invitation for your friend for a recap of what was discussed in the earlier conversation - whereas the previous sentences would have been more asking for a status update.